# Angular 4 project with jquery not working

Tags: jquery, angular

I tried everything I could and I ended up with jquery to solve a situation I have. However, I can't get jquery to work on my Angular 4 project.

- jQuery is loaded via CDN, both minified and uncompressed versions, on my index.html.
- $ and jQuery variables were both declared in the component, right below the imports, as type any.
- both on ngOnInit and ngAfterViewInit I try to change the background color of an element just to check if its working, but the element is still there, unchanged.
- there are no console errors for that.
- if I go to the browser console and run the jQuery method to change the color, it works pretty fine.

So, here is how I'm trying to change the color of this element, which ended up as I still can't use jQuery with my Angular 4 project.

```
jQuery(this.eleRef.nativeElement).find("#xyz").css("background", "blue");
jQuery("#xyz").css("background", "blue");
$(this.eleRef.nativeElement).find("#xyz").css("background", "blue");
$("#xyz").css("background", "blue");
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You should not use jQuery with Angular. 
where you have this code? and `this` is depend on the location you used

Comment: you're right, I shouldn't. But there is not decent range slider fully compatible with Angular 4 and I need to implement one that uses jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is an Angular bug or something else. But, as the name suggests, `ngAfterViewInit` is supposed to have the view properly set in order to handle the dom elements, however, that's not the case if you are not using pure JavaScript.

To solve the problem I created a control where it executes only once on the `ngAfterViewChecked` to setup the elements I needed with JQuery and boom, working.

Hope it helps someone else.